# Create custom EditText in Android

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, typeface

I want to apply new fonts with different styles for all my EditText throughout my project. I tried to do that by creating CustomEditText class which extends EditText as below:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

public static String LATO_BOLD = "fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf";
public static String LATO_LIGHT = "fonts/Lato-Light.ttf";
public static String LATO_REGULAR = "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf";
public static String LATO_BLACK = "fonts/Lato-Black.ttf";

private static final int BOLD = 1;
private static final int LIGHT = 2;
private static final int REGULAR = 3;
private static final int BLACK = 4;

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    init();
}

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (isInEditMode())
        return;

    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.com_pts_mm_android_views_CustomEditText, 0, 0);
    final int fontType = a.getInt(0, -1);

    a.recycle();
    switch (fontType) {
        case LIGHT:
             setLight();
             break;
        case BOLD:
             setBold();
             break;
        case REGULAR:
            init();
            break;
        case BLACK:
            setBlack();
            break;
        default:
            init();
            break;
    }

}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            LATO_REGULAR);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}

public void setLight() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            LATO_LIGHT);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}

public void setBold() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            LATO_BOLD);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}

public void setBlack() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            LATO_BLACK);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

I have all my font files (ttf files) under /assets/fonts folder. Then the attribute and stylables are defined in attrs.xml as below:

```
<attr name="custom_font">
    <enum name="bold" value="1" />
    <enum name="light" value="2" />
    <enum name="regular" value="3" />
    <enum name="black" value="4" />    
</attr>

<declare-styleable name="com.pts.mm.android.views.CustomEditText">
    <attr name="custom_font" />
</declare-styleable>
```

So now I make use of this custom EditText in my layout as below:

```
    <com.pts.mm.android.views.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/etNric"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/edit_box_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/edit_box_horizontal_padding"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/paragraph_vertical_margin"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_edit_size"
    android:textColor="@color/text_edit_color"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox_userid1"
    custom_font="regular"/>
```

However, this does not work. My EditText field becomes non-editable (The cursor just dissapears). Does anyone have any clue what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your prefix for `custom_font` on your editText xml?

Comment: OK, I have tried to define namespace following this instruction [link](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html), but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

editText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

Comment: Set typeface in the code is ok, but I want to achieve it with custom attribute in xml.